# Is it wrong to use "try catch" inside a reactive stream operator(project reactor)?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I was exploring reactive streams with project reactor, and I had a use case where I needed to skip to the next event if an error occurred during the processing of the current event (e.g., deserialization error).

For such a use case, I found out that I can use the `onErrorContinue` operator, but I also thought about wrapping my callback with a `try catch` like this:

```
Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).mapNotNull(item -> {                                                         
    try {                                                                                             
        System.out.println("item = " + item);                                                         
        if (item.equals(3)) throw new IllegalArgumentException(); // deserialization issue for example
        return item;                                                                                  
    } catch (Exception exception){                                                                    
        System.out.println(exception);                                                                
        return null;                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                 
}).subscribe(item -> System.out.println("got element :" + item));
```

I have found this old [issue](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/572) before the introduction of `onErrorContinue` opperator where someone was complaining about having to wrap his callbacks in a try catch to solve the issue as I have shown in the example.

So I am wondering if there is a reason to prefer `onErrorContinue` over the second approach other than sticking to the functional reactive programming style, maybe? And if there is something wrong with the try-catch approach?

Answer (score 2):

In Reactive Streams when an error is signaled, the publisher is considered terminated:

> [Terminal State](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm#term_terminal_state): For a `Publisher`: When `onComplete` or `onError` has been signalled. For a `Subscriber`: When an `onComplete` or `onError` has been received.

In order to prevent the termination of the `Publisher` in Reactor, you can `try/catch` or use `onErrorContinue` depending on your requirements.

In my opinion there is nothing wrong with `try/catch` and sometimes like in the following scenario, it's the best solution, because `onErrorContinue` will skip all error events, and sometimes you will handle terminal and non-terminal exceptions in the same chain of operators, for example:

```java
        Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
            .map(item -> {
                System.out.println("item = " + item);
                if (item.equals(5)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Terminal event"); // terminal exception
                }
                return item;
            })
            .mapNotNull(item -> {
                System.out.println("item = " + item);
                if (item.equals(3))  {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non-terminal event"); // non-terminal exception
                }
                return item;
            })
            .onErrorContinue((error, item) -> {
                System.out.println(error.getMessage());
            }).subscribe(item -> System.out.println("got element :" + item));
```

In this scenario, both exceptions thrown are the same type, but one is considered a terminal event. The correct solution for this problem in my opinion is using `try/catch` inside `flatMap/concatMap` instead of `onErrorContinue`:

```java
        Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
            .map(item -> {
                System.out.println("item = " + item);
                if (item.equals(5)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Terminal event"); // terminal exception
                }
                return item;
            })
            .concatMap(item -> {
                System.out.println("item = " + item);
                try {
                    if (item.equals(3))  {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non-terminal event"); // non-terminal exception
                    }
                    return Flux.just(item);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    return Flux.empty();
                }
            })
            .subscribe(item -> System.out.println("got element :" + item));
```

This way the terminal event will end the `Publisher`, and the non-terminal event will be processed, preventing the emission by returning `Flux.empty()` in case of exception.

Comment: For the case you've shown It is also possible to solve It with onErrorContinue since you get the exception as a param, but I agree using try-catch is probably cleaner and more readable.